# Strava REST API | swagger-client does not return full DetailedAthelete reperesentation

Tags: python, rest, strava

I'm trying to build application around Strava.com REST API using swagger-client. I've successfully got access token and run API calls. What makes a problem is a API call getLoggedInAthlete which (according to [documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Athletes-getLoggedInAthlete)) is supposed to return an instance of DetailedAthlete while it only contains limited set of fileds (8 vs 32 expected). If I run same API call via Postman/curl I get the full representation including all fields.

I need to get full representation of DetailedAthlete including all fields (i.e. id, firstname, lastname etc) - appreciate any ideas.

Steps to reproduce:

- Per their [documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/) I've installed swagger-codegen@2 via brew.
- Generated client: `swagger-codegen generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l python -o generated/python`
- Installed client: `cd generated/python && python setup.py install && cd ../..`
- Call API to retrieve logged athlete (I already have authorization token with *read_all* scope that is required to get DetailedAthlete representation).

```
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException


def get_athl():

    configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
    configuration.access_token = <my token here>

    api_instance = swagger_client.AthletesApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))

    try:
        r = api_instance.get_logged_in_athlete()
    except ApiException as e:
        print(e)

    return r
```

I receive an instance of DetailedAthlete which only includes fields of DetailedAthlete but not of SummaryAthlete. In contrast to POST request to https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete which returns full representation. Here for comparison what I get form swagger-client vs curl request:
[image: swagger-client vs curl]

Comment: I am working on strava api. How did you get to the code in `get_athl`? The code in documentation gives error.

Comment: Hi, I'm actually managed to get it work based on code from documentation. 
```
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException

def swagger_get_athlete(token: str):
    configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
    configuration.access_token = token
    api_instance = swagger_client.AthletesApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))
    try:
        # Get Authenticated Athlete
        api_response = api_instance.get_logged_in_athlete()
        return api_response
    except ApiException as e:
        print("getLoggedInAthlete: %s\n" %e)
```

Comment: `api_instance = swagger_client.AthletesApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))`, I didn't find this line on the documentation, I was looking here, https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Athletes-getLoggedInAthlete for python